# Golang & Google Spreadsheet API V4 - Unable to read a sheet

Tags: go, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I've been following the https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go but I couldn't make it work. In fact, I am getting all the time this error:

```
2019/01/20 14:39:00 Unable to retrieve data from sheet: Get https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[..............]?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I first changed the *spreadsheetId* and the *readRange* of the quickstart:

```
// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
spreadsheetId := "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"
readRange := "Class Data!A2:E"
resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
}

if len(resp.Values) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("No data found.")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Name, Major:")
    for _, row := range resp.Values {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[4])
    }
}
```

Because, since I have already implemented the Google Drive API V3, I put an id of a spreadsheet I have (and used the credentials.json of the account that created this spreadsheet)

However, I am still getting this error, any idea why?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the account you're using to read the spreadsheet the same as the account that owns/created the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes it’s the same account, I downloaded the credentials from this account. At first, the folders were created by another account but I transferred all the ownerships to this new account and this new account created the given spreadsheet :)

Comment: The spreadhseet need to be public if you are using API key